# Draw text for graph axis description

Tags: skiasharp

I am drawing a graph using SkiaSharp. Now I want to add the axis description (Monday, Tuesday, ...) on the X-Axis.

The important code here is:

```
foreach(string key in surveyAnswers.Keys)
            {
                SKPath currentTextPath = new SKPath();
                currentTextPath.MoveTo((float)(info.Width * borderOffset + i * xStepSize - 70), (float)(info.Height * borderOffset + (answerPossibilitiesCount - 1) * yStepSize + 70));
                currentTextPath.RLineTo(70, -70);

                canvas.DrawTextOnPath(key, currentTextPath, 0, 0, paint);
                i++;
            }
```

It provides me with correctly positioned path, on which I am drawing the text. The problem is that the path has a fixed length. I am making it 70 high and wide, which leaves space on shorter texts and cuts the longer ones.

An example can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZBGc.png).

I have thought of a few ways to solve the issue, though none work, since they require unsupported operations or information that I do not have.

How can I align the text with the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with a pathLength variable which depends on the font size and the text length.

```
float pathLenght = (float)((key.Length * (17.0f/25.0f * textSize)) / Math.Sqrt(2));
```

The ratio of 17/25 seems to work just fine on many font sizes.

Just if anyone could need it I post the code above with inserted solution

```
foreach(string key in surveyAnswers.Keys)
            {
                float pathLenght = (float)((key.Length * (17.0f/25.0f * textSize)) / Math.Sqrt(2));
                SKPath currentTextPath = new SKPath();
                currentTextPath.MoveTo((float)(info.Width * borderOffset + i * xStepSize - pathLenght), (float)(info.Height * borderOffset + (answerPossibilitiesCount - 1) * yStepSize + pathLenght));
                currentTextPath.RLineTo(pathLenght, -pathLenght);

                canvas.DrawTextOnPath(key, currentTextPath, 0, 0, paint);
                i++;
            }
```